# Arraylist Index out of bound

Tags: java, regex, for-loop, arraylist, collections

The homework requires reading two file and entering the information of students into two separate `ArrayList`s. Then I need to perform 2 functions: combine the two lists and sort the combined list.

```
public abstract class Tools {
    public static ArrayList<JUPASStudent> readJUPASFile(String f) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<JUPASStudent> jList = new ArrayList<JUPASStudent>();

        BufferedReader readbuffer = null;
        readbuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String strRead;
        while ((strRead = readbuffer.readLine()) != null) {
            String splitarray[] = strRead.split("/t");
            String firstentry = splitarray[0];
            String secondentry = splitarray[1];
            JUPASStudent x = new JUPASStudent(firstentry, Double.parseDouble(secondentry));
            jList.add(x);
        }

        readbuffer.close();
        return jList;
        }

    public static ArrayList<NonJUPASStudent> readNonJUPASFile(String f) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<NonJUPASStudent> njList = new ArrayList<NonJUPASStudent>();

        BufferedReader readbuffer = null;
        readbuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String strRead;
        while ((strRead = readbuffer.readLine()) != null) {
            String splitarray[] = strRead.split("/t");
            String firstentry = splitarray[0];
            String secondentry = splitarray[1];
            NonJUPASStudent x = new NonJUPASStudent(firstentry, Double.parseDouble(secondentry));
            njList.add(x);
        }

        readbuffer.close();
        return njList;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Student> combineArrayList(ArrayList<JUPASStudent> S1, ArrayList<NonJUPASStudent> S2) {
        ArrayList<Student> sList = new ArrayList<Student>();

        for (int i = 0; i < S1.size(); i++)
            sList.add(S1.get(i));
        for (int i = 0; i < S2.size(); i++) 
            sList.add(S2.get(i));

        return sList;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Student> sort(ArrayList<Student> s){
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size()-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < s.size()-i-1; j++) {
                if (s.get(j).getResult() > s.get(j+1).getResult()) {
                    Student Temp = s.get(j);
                    s.set(j, s.get(j+1));
                    s.set(j+1, Temp);
                }
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting "Index 1 out of bounds for length 1"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and note that when asking about exceptions you should post the stacktrace and mark the lines of your code mentioned there. In short the message you're getting means that you're trying to access index 1 of an array that only has index 0 (i.e. length 1).

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing  might be in the below line.
in method readNonJUPASFile and readJUPASFile

```
String secondentry = splitarray[1];
```

You are splitting the String based on /t. If you are expecting to split it based on tab you should be giving \t. If your line does not contain /t as you have given you will probably get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. You should check the length before assigning the variable like

```
if (splitarray.length > 1) {
   String firstentry = splitarray[0];
   String secondentry = splitarray[1];
}
```

Comment: Huge thanks. Solved the error

Comment: Please accept this answer.

Comment: Please check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

In the inner loop you're defining a constraint to the wrong counter. Instead of :

```
for (int j = 0; i < s.size()-i-1; j++)
```

there should be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < s.size()-i-1; j++)
```

Comment: Good spot. One more example for why more meaningful variable names help reduce bugs that result from typos (or confusing variables).

Comment: thanks, I just amended the code but the problem remains unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

In package java.util, we can :

- Collections.sort(List); // to sort list, ex:

`Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(13, 4));`

- Collections.addAll(Collection c, T... elements); // to join list, ex :

`Collections.addAll(Arrays.asList(13, 4), Arrays.asList(3,4,5));`

So you don't need to write your own function anymore.

Comment: I can't use the collections.sort due to homework restriction :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you add few system.out statements. It will help you see where the error. I suspect data from file.